# jQuery Mobile Footer Push To The Bottom of the Page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to have a footer that is always pushed to the bottom of the page. So that when the page has a short content, the footer will be **at the bottom of the screen** and if the content is long, then the footer will be **after the content**. How will I do that?

**NOTE:** I am not looking for the `data-position="fixed"`.

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT:** Are there any other way/s I can get what I want? I have tried [Ryan Fait's trick](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. The page cannot be scrolled anymore. So, are there any other way/s?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the min-height attribute of the jQM content div to accomplish this. Below, the SetMinHeight function calculates the minimum height for the content div that would fill the given device height. Then you call it on pagecontainershow and whenever the window resizes or the orientation changes:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

function SetMinHeight() {
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    $(".ui-content").css("min-height", content + "px");
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jzByk/4/)**

Try resizing the panel in the demo and you will see the footer only goes down when the content no longer fits the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be jquery mobile compatible and safe.

You can test your site on mobile devices with a nice chrome extension called Ripple

[Ripple extension, Can be found here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/related)!

The fun part of this extension is the fact you can also use your chrome developer tools to tweak on the fly. Multiple emulator options for many devices.

Comment: I have tried the trick that I linked, but it don't work. :( Are there any other way/s to get what I want?

Comment: Just tested and this trick does it:
 http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/